# How can I do this SQLite query?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

While I have more experience with MySQL, i'm fairly new to SQLite and apparently there is no support in it's syntax for IF() statements, so I was wondering, how can I do this query which works great in MySQL, but in SQLite?

```
SELECT auth_user.email,
   Sum(IF((brasil2014_partidosfifa.Local = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Local AND brasil2014_partidosfifa.Visita = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Visita),2,0) + IF(brasil2014_partidosfifa.Resultado = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Resultado,1,0)) AS puntos
FROM brasil2014_partidosfifa
INNER JOIN brasil2014_partidosusuarios ON brasil2014_partidosfifa.id = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.id
INNER JOIN auth_user ON brasil2014_partidosusuarios.idUsuario_id = auth_user.id
WHERE auth_user.id LIKE '%' AND brasil2014_partidosfifa.Jugado = 'Si'
GROUP BY auth_user.email
ORDER BY puntos DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's an awfully long statement for one line. Consider breaking it up into multiple lines.

Comment: Try looking into CASE WHEN, which is the standard SQL construct to use in most RDBMS that have no support for IIF or equivalent function. (http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)

Answer (score 1):

try a [case expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case). Instead of

```
Sum(IF((brasil2014_partidosfifa.Local = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Local AND 
        brasil2014_partidosfifa.Visita = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Visita),2,0) + 
    IF( brasil2014_partidosfifa.Resultado = brasil2014_partidosusuarios.Resultado,1,0)) 
    AS puntos
```

use:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (  ... your first IF ... ) THEN 2 ELSE 0
END + 
CASE 
    WHEN (  ... your second IF ... ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END 
AS puntos
```

Comment: That's it! I had it nearly figured out but I was missing the END statements. Thanks!